# When connected to two networks, can I tell my iMac to use a specific network for a certain application?

Tags: network, wifi, mojave

I run Spotify on wifi network "Production Internet". As the name implies, that network has internet access.

I'd also like to run [Audiofusion SoundCaster](https://audiofusionsystems.com/soundcaster/) over a separate hardwired network that doesn't have internet access. Well, actually the iMac would be hardwired to a different wifi router with no internet access. So the SoundCaster traffic eventually goes over a wifi network called "Monitors". "Monitors" doesn't have internet access, though. It only carries SoundCaster traffic between iPhones and the iMac.

I don't want SoundCaster traffic going over "Production Internet". How can I force all SoundCaster traffic to go to the hardwired connection so it is sent to the wifi router for "Monitors"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got a great answer from the Audiofusion team. It resolves my specific situation.

Per Audiofusion:

> SoundCaster will only send audio over the Ethernet connection. Just
> make sure the WiFi connection is listed first and the Ethernet
> connection is listed second in your Network Preferences.

Thanks!